# How do you create a universal shortcut to Roaming

Tags: shortcuts

I need help, (of course) I am trying to create a shortcut that leads to `C:\Users\"user"\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft`
So what can I do? Because whenever I hit it it works on my computer but when my friend hits it it doesn't work. It will just say "File Not Found" (not specifically but to make things short and without the quotes.) So can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the shortcut point to

```
%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming.minecraft
```

or alternatively

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\..\Roaming.minecraft
```

BTW, `Roaming.minecraft` seems like typo to me. You probably mean `Roaming\minecraft`.

Answer (score 1):

"%APPDATA%" seems by default to take me directly to the "AppData\Roaming" folder location. Whatever folders I append to it follows the path.

Don't know why, how, or if it works universally, but I just figured it out through trial and error.

Comment: It's called an environment variable https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html